# Magento 2 : What is the correct namespace of Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item?

Tags: magento2.2

What is the correct namespace of "Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address_Item" in Magento 2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for

```
<?php

namespace Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;

class Item extends \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Item\AbstractItem
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check file on below path:**

> vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/Quote/Address/Item.php

```
namespace Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address;
```